# Redirection to dashboard after login in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-router-dom

I have a login page, and I want to redirect users to dashboard after the details are filled.
I have tried using history.push and redirect components but I couldn't redirect.

**Login Page**

```
class Login extends React.Component {

    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {},
        redirect: false
    }

    validateForm = () => {
        let errors = {};
        let formIsValid = true;

        if(!this.state.email) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors['email'] = 'Please enter email to continue';
        }

        if(!this.state.password) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors['password'] = 'Please enter password to continue';
        }

        this.setState({
            errors: errors
        })

        return formIsValid;
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log(this.state);
        if(this.validateForm()) {
            const loginData = {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            }
            axios
                .post('/users.json', loginData)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
                    <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Login</h5>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <p>{this.state.errors.email}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <p>{this.state.errors.password}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                    <button onClick={this.redirectHandler} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

export default Login;

I want to redirect to other page once the form is submitted with the email and password.
I've been trying this for days but I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Login extends React.Component {

    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {},
        redirect: false
    }

    validateForm = () => {
        let errors = {};
        let formIsValid = true;

        if(!this.state.email) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors['email'] = 'Please enter email to continue';
        }

        if(!this.state.password) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors['password'] = 'Please enter password to continue';
        }

        this.setState({
            errors: errors
        })

        return formIsValid;
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log(this.state);
        if(this.validateForm()) {
            const loginData = {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            }
            axios
                .post('/users.json', loginData)
                .then(response => {
                    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
                    <h5 className="grey-text text-darken-3">Login</h5>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <p>{this.state.errors.email}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        <p>{this.state.errors.password}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                    <button onClick={this.redirectHandler} className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Answer (score 0):

have some complain about your code.

1. first: for form validation and handling you dont need to use state,
   there is a library called [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) which will help you a lot with
   this.
2. second: if you are using redux to check user is logged in  or
   not you need to create a private route for routes which cannot be
   accessible for public like here `dashboard` component.
3. third: to use history you need to wrap your
   component inside `withRouter` HOC which will pass route props to your
   component so you can use `history` or if your are using functional component you can use `useHistory()` hook.